# Write COM registry settings and then CoGetClassObject fails

Tags: c++, winapi, com, registry

I am trying to implement the following scenario. 
Register COM object on the "HKEY_CURRENT_USER" hive and then call it using CoGetClassObject. To register I write directly to registry using Windows API.

```
CRegKey keyInProcServer32;
string keyPathProcServer = "Software\\Classes\\CLSID\\" + strClassId + "\\InProcServer32";
long lRet = keyInProcServer32.Create( HKEY_CURRENT_USER, keyPathProcServer.c_str() );

...
GUID classId = ClassIdFromString( IDS_CLASSID );
IUnknown *pClassFactory = NULL;
HRESULT hr = CoGetClassObject(
    classId,
    CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    NULL,
    IID_IClassFactory,
    reinterpret_cast< LPVOID* >( &pClassFactory ) );
```

The call to CoGetClassObject failes with REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG
Is there a way to make COM activation mechanism aware that the library was just registered ?

Comment: So the server does not implement dllregisterserver()?

Comment: You only created the key, you did not set its value.

Comment: The code here is incomplete. I create all the keys and values. After I restart the application CoGetClassObject works as expected.

Comment: Server does not implement DllRegisterServer. I perform registration from code